# How to clone an object but with only some key/values?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  createdAt: "2016-01-25T04:01:53.282Z"
  index: 0
  objectId: "56a59e31a633bd0257868cb8"
  panoDataRotate: 0
  roomModelId: "56a59e242e958a00596a897c"
  x: 240
  y: 230
}
```

I want to clone it but into an object that only has index`,`x`, and`y`:

```
{
  index: 0
  x: 240
  y: 230
}
```

How to do that with lodash/Underscore?

Comment: damn, too bad you want to use a library - easy enough with just javascript - oh well

Comment: Have you read docs? https://lodash.com/docs#pick

Comment: @AlexeyTen Damn, I found it after I posted this question. I wanted to delete it but I can't because there are answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lodash, you could use this:

```
var obj = {
  createdAt: "2016-01-25T04:01:53.282Z",
  index: 0,
  objectId: "56a59e31a633bd0257868cb8",
  panoDataRotate: 0,
  roomModelId: "56a59e242e958a00596a897c",
  x: 240,
  y: 230
};
var newObject = _.pick(obj, ['index', 'x', 'y']);
```

See [here](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) the docs for `_.pick()` function.

And a plain JavaScript solution:

```
var obj = {
  createdAt: "2016-01-25T04:01:53.282Z",
  index: 0,
  objectId: "56a59e31a633bd0257868cb8",
  panoDataRotate: 0,
  roomModelId: "56a59e242e958a00596a897c",
  x: 240,
  y: 230
};
var newObject = ['index', 'x', 'y'].reduce(function(result, key) {
  result[key] = obj[key];
  return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### for-in on data

You can use `for-in` to loop over properties of an object.

```js
var data = {
  createdAt: "2016-01-25T04:01:53.282Z",
  index: 0,
  objectId: "56a59e31a633bd0257868cb8",
  panoDataRotate: 0,
  roomModelId: "56a59e242e958a00596a897c",
  x: 240,
  y: 230
}

var allowedKeys = ["x", "y", "index"];
var result = {};
for (var key in data){
  if(allowedKeys.indexOf(key)>-1){
    result[key] = data[key];
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

#### forEach over allowedKeys array

You can also loop over array of allowed keys to reduce code.

**Note:** *In this approach, if key is not present in `data`, `undefined` will be assigned to it. But in prior approach, this key will be inserted.*

For demo purpose, I have added a key `test` to `allowedKeys` array.

```js
var data = {
  createdAt: "2016-01-25T04:01:53.282Z",
  index: 0,
  objectId: "56a59e31a633bd0257868cb8",
  panoDataRotate: 0,
  roomModelId: "56a59e242e958a00596a897c",
  x: 240,
  y: 230
}

var allowedKeys = ["x", "y", "index", "test"];
var result = {};
allowedKeys.forEach(function(key){
  result[key] = data[key];
})

console.log(result)
```